# How can I add a store a cookie function to this five star rating system?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, ip-address

I have added a custom script for a five star rating system to my header.php file in wordpress (I did not add a wp_enqueue_scripts hook when I probably should have). The javascript is operational but I have noting implemented in the code to prevent multiple votes from the same IP Address. I wanted to see if there is some way I can add a store cookie function to check the IP of the voters to the custom code in the header.php file or to the ratings.php file?

I greatly appreciate any advice you can provide!

Here is the custom code from the header.php file:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rate_widget').each(function(i) {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            widget_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post(
            'http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/themes/skt-magazine/ratings.php',
            out_data,
            function(INFO) {
                $(widget).data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });


    $('.ratings_stars').hover(

        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        },

        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');

            set_votes($(this).parent());
        }
    );



    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            'http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/themes/skt-magazine/ratings.php',
            clicked_data,
            function(INFO) {
                widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        ); 
    });



});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);

    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}
// END FIRST THING








</script>
```

```
    .rate_widget {
        overflow:   visible;
        padding:    10px;
        position:   relative;
        width:      180px;
        height:     32px;
    }
    .ratings_stars {
        background: url('http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/star_empty_hc.png') no-repeat;
        float:      left;
        height:     28px;
        padding:    2px;
        width:      32px;
    }
    .ratings_vote {
        background: url('http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/star_full_hc2.png') no-repeat;
    }
    .ratings_over {
        background: url('http://localhost/url/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/star_highlight_hc.png') no-repeat;
    }
    .total_votes {
        background: #eaeaea;
        top: 58px;
        left: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        position:   absolute;  
    } 
    .movie_choice {
        font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0 0 40px 0;
        width: 180px;
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }
</style>
```

And here is the ratings.php file that I had mentioned:

```
<?php


$rating = new ratings($_POST['widget_id']);


isset($_POST['fetch']) ? $rating->get_ratings() : $rating->vote();






class ratings {

var $data_file = 'ratings.data.txt';
private $widget_id;
private $data = array();


function __construct($wid) {

$this->widget_id = $wid;

$all = file_get_contents($this->data_file);

if($all) {
    $this->data = unserialize($all);
}
 }
 public function get_ratings() {
if($this->data[$this->widget_id]) {
    echo json_encode($this->data[$this->widget_id]);
}
else {
    $data['widget_id'] = $this->widget_id;
    $data['number_votes'] = 0;
    $data['total_points'] = 0;
    $data['dec_avg'] = 0;
    $data['whole_avg'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($data);
} 
}
public function vote() {


preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
$vote = $match[1];

$ID = $this->widget_id;

if($this->data[$ID]) {
    $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] += 1;
    $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] += $vote;
}

else {
    $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] = 1;
    $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] = $vote;
}

$this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] = round( $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] / $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'], 1 );
$this->data[$ID]['whole_avg'] = round( $this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] );


file_put_contents($this->data_file, serialize($this->data));
$this->get_ratings();
}


}
?>
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused by your question, are you looking for how to get the IP of a visitor?

Comment: Hi @HansStrausl, I am trying to add a cookie to the script to make sure only one IP address has one vote for the five star rating. With the way the script is set up now anyone can vote as many times as they want from the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Implement something like this

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("voted=") >= 0) {
  // They've voted before.
  canVote = false;
} else {
  // set a new cookie
  expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setTime(date.getTime()+(1000*24*60*60*1000)); // 1000 days

  // Date()'s toGMTSting() method will format the date correctly for a cookie
  document.cookie = "voted=yes; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  canVote = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your time to give me a good tip on this! I sincerely appreciate your response and will test something like this out!